# Python 3 equivalent to code involving tuples passed to a function

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a code which calculates the movie similarities given a dataset, which is ratings.dat and movies.dat. The code however, is written in python 2.7.

I tried converting the code to python-3 but was unable to get the desired results. Need some expert help to review if there are any mistakes in the code.

Below is the code is the code area which I need to convert to python 3:

```
def makePairs((user, ratings)):
    (movie1, rating1) = ratings[0]
    (movie2, rating2) = ratings[1]
    return ((movie1, movie2), (rating1, rating2))

def filterDuplicates( (userID, ratings) ):
    (movie1, rating1) = ratings[0]
    (movie2, rating2) = ratings[1]
    return movie1 < movie2
```

and also this

```
  # Filter for movies with this sim that are "good" as defined by
    # our quality thresholds above
    filteredResults = moviePairSimilarities.filter(lambda((pair,sim)): \
        (pair[0] == movieID or pair[1] == movieID) \
        and sim[0] > scoreThreshold and sim[1] > coOccurenceThreshold)

    # Sort by quality score.
    results = filteredResults.map(lambda((pair,sim)): (sim, pair)).sortByKey(ascending = False).take(10)
```

the complete code as follows

```
spark-submit mycodefile.py 50
```

here's the code in python 2.7

```
import sys
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from math import sqrt

def loadMovieNames():
    movieNames = {}
    with open("movies.dat") as f:
        for line in f:
            fields = line.split("::")
            movieNames[int(fields[0])] = fields[1].decode('ascii', 'ignore')
    return movieNames

def makePairs((user, ratings)):
    (movie1, rating1) = ratings[0]
    (movie2, rating2) = ratings[1]
    return ((movie1, movie2), (rating1, rating2))

def filterDuplicates( (userID, ratings) ):
    (movie1, rating1) = ratings[0]
    (movie2, rating2) = ratings[1]
    return movie1 < movie2

def computeCosineSimilarity(ratingPairs):
    numPairs = 0
    sum_xx = sum_yy = sum_xy = 0
    for ratingX, ratingY in ratingPairs:
        sum_xx += ratingX * ratingX
        sum_yy += ratingY * ratingY
        sum_xy += ratingX * ratingY
        numPairs += 1

    numerator = sum_xy
    denominator = sqrt(sum_xx) * sqrt(sum_yy)

    score = 0
    if (denominator):
        score = (numerator / (float(denominator)))

    return (score, numPairs)


conf = SparkConf()
sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)

print("\nLoading movie names...")
nameDict = loadMovieNames()

data = sc.textFile("ratings.dat")

# Map ratings to key / value pairs: user ID => movie ID, rating
ratings = data.map(lambda l: l.split("::")).map(lambda l: (int(l[0]), (int(l[1]), float(l[2]))))

# Emit every movie rated together by the same user.
# Self-join to find every combination.
ratingsPartitioned = ratings.partitionBy(100)
joinedRatings = ratingsPartitioned.join(ratingsPartitioned)

# At this point our RDD consists of userID => ((movieID, rating), (movieID, rating))

# Filter out duplicate pairs
uniqueJoinedRatings = joinedRatings.filter(filterDuplicates)

# Now key by (movie1, movie2) pairs.
moviePairs = uniqueJoinedRatings.map(makePairs).partitionBy(100)

# We now have (movie1, movie2) => (rating1, rating2)
# Now collect all ratings for each movie pair and compute similarity
moviePairRatings = moviePairs.groupByKey()

# We now have (movie1, movie2) = > (rating1, rating2), (rating1, rating2) ...
# Can now compute similarities.
moviePairSimilarities = moviePairRatings.mapValues(computeCosineSimilarity).persist()

# Save the results if desired
moviePairSimilarities.sortByKey()
moviePairSimilarities.saveAsTextFile("movie-sims")

# Extract similarities for the movie we care about that are "good".
if (len(sys.argv) > 1):

    scoreThreshold = 0.97
    coOccurenceThreshold = 1000

    movieID = int(sys.argv[1])

    # Filter for movies with this sim that are "good" as defined by
    # our quality thresholds above
    filteredResults = moviePairSimilarities.filter(lambda((pair,sim)): \
        (pair[0] == movieID or pair[1] == movieID) \
        and sim[0] > scoreThreshold and sim[1] > coOccurenceThreshold)

    # Sort by quality score.
    results = filteredResults.map(lambda((pair,sim)): (sim, pair)).sortByKey(ascending = False).take(10)

    print("Top 10 similar movies for " + nameDict[movieID])
    for result in results:
        (sim, pair) = result
        # Display the similarity result that isn't the movie we're looking at
        similarMovieID = pair[0]
        if (similarMovieID == movieID):
            similarMovieID = pair[1]
        print(nameDict[similarMovieID] + "\tscore: " + str(sim[0]) + "\tstrength: " + str(sim[1]))
```

any help is much appreciated.

Regard

what I have already done is converting this code to a python 3 equivalent code as follows, but unable to get the desired results.

```
import sys
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from math import sqrt

def loadMovieNames():
    movieNames = {}
    with open("movies.dat") as f:
        for line in f:
            fields = line.split("::")
            movieNames[int(fields[0])] = fields[1] #.decode('ascii', 'ignore')
    return movieNames

def makePairs(*ratings):
    for t in ratings:
        (movie1, rating1) = t[1][0]
        (movie2, rating2) = t[1][1]    
    return ((movie1, movie2), (rating1, rating2))

def filterDuplicates(*ratings):    
    for t in ratings:
        (movie1, rating1) = t[1][0]
        (movie2, rating2) = t[1][1]
    return movie1 < movie2

def computeCosineSimilarity(ratingPairs):
    numPairs = 0
    sum_xx = sum_yy = sum_xy = 0
    for ratingX, ratingY in ratingPairs:
        sum_xx += ratingX * ratingX
        sum_yy += ratingY * ratingY
        sum_xy += ratingX * ratingY
        numPairs += 1

    numerator = sum_xy
    denominator = sqrt(sum_xx) * sqrt(sum_yy)

    score = 0
    if (denominator):
        score = (numerator / (float(denominator)))

    return (score, numPairs)

conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]").setAppName("MovieSimilarities")
sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)

print("\nLoading movie names...")
nameDict = loadMovieNames()

print("\nLoading movie ratings...")
data = sc.textFile("ratings100.dat")

print("\nDone..")

# Map ratings to key / value pairs: user ID => movie ID, rating
ratings = data.map(lambda l: l.split("::")).map(lambda l: (int(l[0]), (int(l[1]), float(l[2]))))

# Emit every movie rated together by the same user.
# Self-join to find every combination.

ratingsPartitioned = ratings.partitionBy(100)
joinedRatings = ratingsPartitioned.join(ratingsPartitioned)
#joinedRatings = ratings.join(ratings)


# At this point our RDD consists of userID => ((movieID, rating), (movieID, rating))
# Filter out duplicate pairs

uniqueJoinedRatings = joinedRatings.filter(filterDuplicates)

# Now key by (movie1, movie2) pairs.
moviePairs = uniqueJoinedRatings.map(makePairs).partitionBy(100)

# We now have (movie1, movie2) => (rating1, rating2)
# Now collect all ratings for each movie pair and compute similarity
moviePairRatings = moviePairs.groupByKey()

# We now have (movie1, movie2) = > (rating1, rating2), (rating1, rating2) ...
# Can now compute similarities.
moviePairSimilarities = moviePairRatings.mapValues(computeCosineSimilarity).persist()

# Save the results if desired
moviePairSimilarities.sortByKey()
moviePairSimilarities.saveAsTextFile("movie-sims")

# Extract similarities for the movie we care about that are "good".
if (len(sys.argv) > 1):

    scoreThreshold = 0.9
    coOccurenceThreshold = 1000

    movieID = int(sys.argv[1])

    # Filter for movies with this sim that are "good" as defined by
    # our quality thresholds above    

    filteredResults = moviePairSimilarities.filter(lambda pairSim:  (pairSim[0][0] == movieID or pairSim[0][1] == movieID) and pairSim[1][0] > scoreThreshold and pairSim[1][1] > coOccurenceThreshold)

    # Sort by quality score.
    results = filteredResults.map(lambda pairSim: (pairSim[1], pairSim[0])).sortByKey(ascending = False).take(10)

    print("Top 10 similar movies for " + str(nameDict[movieID]))
    for result in results:
        (sim, pair) = result
        # Display the similarity result that isn't the movie we're looking at
        similarMovieID = pair[0]
        if (similarMovieID == movieID):
            similarMovieID = pair[1]
        print(nameDict[similarMovieID] + "\tscore: " + str(sim[0]) + "\tstrength: " + str(sim[1]))
```

Below is expected result, which should show top 10 similar movie results.

```
Top 10 similar movies for Wizard of Oz, The (1939)
Toy Story (1995)        score: 661      strength: 1545
Some Other Movie        score: 594      strength: 720
Another Movie           score: 2018     strength: 2804
```

Comment: ratings.dat format  = 1::1193::5::978300760, which is userID::movID::rating::timestamp ... ratings can be 1 to 5

Comment: movies.dat format movieID::moviename

Comment: what result did you currently get?

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include this information in the question itself, instead of down here in the comments. Also, please provide a [mre] - I could not quickly see which part of your code you actually need help with.

Comment: Aren't you simply looking for [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)?

Comment: I've edited the code and included the parts which I need help with.. actually makePairs and filterDuplicates functions and also the later part of the code where the sorting is being performed.

Comment: @DennisLi this code isn't returning anything yet. what I did was the change in teh function signature of 2.7 .. whcih is  f((x,y)) to f(*tuplex) which is python 3 equiv

Answer (score 0):

`def f(*tuplex)` is not the same as `def f((x, y))`; it is (more or less) the same as `def f(x, y)`. That is, the first (py3) function receives a list of non-keyword argument, the second (py2) a *single* tuple argument. Since you're passing a single-element (which happens to be a tuple), `tuplex` will be a tuple of one element (and the resulting `for t in tuplex` will only iterate once). You should make it `def(xy)`, where `xy` will be your `(x, y)` tuple.

---

Your Python 2 code:

```
def makePairs((user, ratings)):
    (movie1, rating1) = ratings[0]
    (movie2, rating2) = ratings[1]
    return ((movie1, movie2), (rating1, rating2))
```

The actual compatible Python 3 code:

```
def makePairs(user_ratings):
    _, ratings = user_ratings
    (movie1, rating1) = ratings[0]
    (movie2, rating2) = ratings[1]
    return ((movie1, movie2), (rating1, rating2))
```

---

As also mentioned somewhere in the comments, you can replace this whole function by a simple `zip` call, for example:

```
>>> a = (('movie1', 'rating1'), ('movie2', 'rating2'))
>>> list(zip(*a))
[('movie1', 'movie2'), ('rating1', 'rating2')]
```

(you don't need `list(...)` if you just need to return an iterator, but that doesn't show the actual contents on the command line. so leave out the call to `list(...)` unless you get an error about a "zip object" in your actual code.)

The unfortunate parts here are that 
- the `map` method where you use `makePairs` passes only a function, so you can't specify the asterisk.
- you need to get rid of the first argument, `user`.

You could probably use the following:

```
moviePairs = uniqueJoinedRatings.map(lambda x: zip(*x[1])).partitionBy(100)
```

(untested)
That gets rid of the complete `makePairs` function, at the cost of some clarity.

---

Last tidbit: `make_pairs` follows the style guide; `makePairs` is not Python style. As goes for all other names in your code. Since you mentioned the word review at the top of your question (but that's probably more a matter for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks for the response...much appreciated. Let me check on this and I will get back with the results.